# my jsfiddle is not acting nice when transferred live

Tags: jquery

I have a fiddle when transferred live is not acting nice.
http://jsfiddle.net/q9cfa6qu/11/

In my fiddle the states are in columns, but when transferred live they are in rows! There's no difference with the code.

Woring jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q9cfa6qu/11/

Broken jfiddle: http://unclestevesny.com/test-accordion-2/ [live]
http://screencast.com/t/Hu41l12ugS

Here's the HTML. The html, css and jquery is exactly the same as my jfiddle.

```
<div id="storecontainer">
<div class="element_content_header_3">Find a Store</div>
<div class="accordion">
<h2>New York</h2>
<div class="pane">
    <div class="accordion accordion2">
       <h2><img src="http://unclestevesny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Whole-Foods-Market-Logoa.png" alt="Whole Foods Market" /></h2>
        <div class="pane">

             <div class="oestlstore">
                Market 97th St<br />
                 808 Columbus Ave.<br />
               New York, NY 10025
               </div>
               <div class="oestlstore">
                Columbus Circle 10 <br />Columbus Circle <br />New York, NY 10019
               </div>
             <div  class="oestlstore">
                Manhasset <br />2101 Northern Blvd.<br />New York, NY 11030
               </div>
               <div  class="oestlstore">
                Union Square <br />4 Union Square South<br />New York, NY 10003
               </div>

        </div>

<h2 ><img src="http://unclestevesny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/stopshopicon.jpg" alt="Stop & Shop" style="margin-top:10px;" /></h2>
        <div class="pane">
          test
        </div>

<h2><img src="http://unclestevesny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/ShopRiteicon.png" alt="ShopRite" /></h2>
        <div class="pane">
          test
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
<h2>New Jersey</h2>
<div class="pane">
    content
</div>
<h2>California</h2>
<div class="pane">
    content
</div>
<h2>District of Columbia</h2>
<div class="pane">
    content
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [How to use the console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)

Comment: Your problem is the `clear: both` from this file: http://unclestevesny.com/wp-content/themes/koyorest/assets/css/wp.css?ver=3.8.4 , referencing h2, at line 416.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS on your site you have:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    clear: both;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
```

You need them not to clear, so add

```
.accordion h1, .accordion h2, etc...
{
     clear: none;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post this answer :)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. How did you spot it so fast? I couldn't find this for hours, especially because that style sheet with clear:both is not even one that I worked on.